# Make a loop with async elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm developing a function that should loop over and over, here is the simplified code:

```js
function display() {
  var conf = $.ajax({
    url: "get.config.com",
    type: "GET",
    async: true,
    success: function() {
      config = $.parseJSON(conf.responseText);

      for (var i = 0; i < config.length; i++) {
        $("#myIframe").fadeIn(0).queue(function(n) {
          $(this).attr("src", filepath);
          n();
        }).delay(5000)
      }
    }
  });
}

display();
```

As you can see, there is a first Ajax call, and the stuff is done inside success function.

The For loop will run step by step, with a delay of 5s. At the end of the for loop, i would like to reload the display() function.

I have tried callbacks on display(), replacing classic for loop by a $.each Loop, put a display() at the end of the display function ...

Everything finished in a maximum stack exceeded, because, i kown, JS is asynchronous..

Thanks in advance

Comment: The `.delay()` call is for any animation that follows that call - it's not a `pause javascript execution` method.  After the for loop, add: `setTimeout(display, 5000)`

Comment: `At the end of the for loop, i would like to reload the display() function.` Why do you want to do this? AJAX polling is an anti pattern which should be avoided as it puts unnecessary extra load on your server. If you need to keep the UI and server data in sync within a 5 second limit I'd strongly suggest you look in to WebSockets or Server Sent Events instead

Comment: @Rory, Thank you, but you see a simplified code. The sync delay is not 5 seconds, but as you can see, the for loop will display more that one element. The delay is about 10 minutes.

Comment: Ah, ok. In which case @freedomn-m has pointed out the problem - you need to use the animation queue more effectively.